Solution configuration (debug, any cpu) in VS Code
Where can I set the solution configs in VS Code? Specifically $(Configuration) and $(Platform).
I'm porting a project from Visual Studo to VS Code, and this project depends on solution configurations, such as "AnyCPU", "Debug", "Release", and some custom configs too (they already exist in project and solution)
The project is almost entirely ported, I can build the solution, but I can't find where to set the configs for building. (Ex: how do I build against MyDebug|MyCPU instead of standard values?)

You can always try and see how it is done by Visual Studio.
I have enabled Git in sample project directory to show differences after adding new configuraiton:

So, you need to just add appropriate info in sln file, based on existing configurations, for example:
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {A9275432-BBF7-4D9A-9CD5-986125A781CF}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {A9275432-BBF7-4D9A-9CD5-986125A781CF}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {A9275432-BBF7-4D9A-9CD5-986125A781CF}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {A9275432-BBF7-4D9A-9CD5-986125A781CF}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection

And the csproj file:
<Configurations>Debug;Release;NewDebug</Configurations>

UPDATE
To run the project with particular configuration, you can always use dotnet CLI from Visual Studio Code terminal:

open VS Code
open terminal
execute dotnet run specifying what project you want to run and providing option --configuration NewDebug (of course, you will place your name here)

For Platform, I think the --arch parameter of dotnet CLI is the one to use.

That is what the project already has. I want to "select" the configuratoins for building. How do I specify build for "NewDebug" and "AnotherCPU".

@DanielMöller updated answer
